# Sum of two numbers using a for loop

Tags: python

I need to write a program that takes a line of input of the form «number1»+«number2» and outputs the sum of the two numbers.

The following doesn't work:

```
S = input()
s_len = len(S)
for i in range(0, s_len):

    if i == '+':
        num1 = int(S[:i])
        num2 = int(S[:i])
        add = num1+num2
        print(add)
```

Comment: i will always be a number. You want S[i].

Comment: could you please write the whole code. Appreciate it

Comment: Could you add details about the way it fails? Does it throw an error? Is the answer just wrong?

Comment: Nothing is printed. So it's None. So no error. It just doesn't print anything

Comment: check your indentation, specifically the line that is supposed to print.  Remember, integrating matters in python. In this case, printing will only occur if `¡` is a `+` sign. Now why it would ever have that value is a while other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to solve the problem like this:

```
S = input()
sum = 0
num = 0
for i in range(0, len(S)):
    if S[i] != '+':
        num = num * 10 + int(S[i])  #Assuming «number1>> and «number2» can have multiple digits 
    else:
        sum += num
        num = 0

sum += num
print (sum)
```

As mentioned in this answer's comment, you might want to reduce casting cost:

```
S = input()
sum = 0
num = 0
start = 0
for i in range(0, len(S)):
    if S[i] == '+':
        sum += int(S[start:i])
        start = i + 1

sum += int(S[start:len(S)])
print (sum)
```

Assumption: Your string is always in the format you mentioned.

Comment: This will be extremely slow, at least use slicing...

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yeah but reading the comments in your answer, it looks like he isn't interested in a pythonic way but more interested in simple basic level problem solving.

Comment: OP clearly knows to use slicing, so why not just fix the condition? A cast to an int is expensive and you are doing plenty there. There is a difference between sticking to the basics and writing a bad solution.

Comment: Also note that it will print 0 on a string such as `'+++++++'`

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Added assumption and provided a second solution as well to cater your comment.

Comment: Your second solution, if forced to use a loop, is a good one, thanks

Comment: I would take an interest in efficiency if there were a million numbers to be read and added. He has two.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to run your sum using the *for* loop, you could modify your program this way

```
S = input()
s_len = len(S)
for i in range(s_len):
    if S[i] == "+":
        num1 = int(S[:i])
        num2 = int(S[i+1:])
        add = num1 + num2
        print(add)       
        break
```

**However** remember that there are many ways that a program does the same, the main difference is always in the optimality of your program, using an iterator is not the most optimal in this problem, besides this solution don't have any flexibility or chance to errors on the part of the user when entering data, must be in a fairly specific

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an `int` and a `str` in your if-condition, replace the condition by `S[i] == '+'`. Also note that your slice for `num2` should be `S[i+1:]` instead.

But instead of looping through the characters to split at the `'+'`, you should use `str.split`.

```
s = input()

nums = s.split('+')
sum_ = sum(int(x) for x in nums)
```

Comment: I still want to learn it using the for loop if possible

Comment: There I updated the answer, but know that after that exercise you should just use str.split

Comment: I am a beginner at python and want to learn based on the thing I have learned so far. Can you please do it without enumerate? appreciate it

Comment: There I explained your error, know that you still should use str.split in the future

Comment: Also can use `sum(map(int, nums))`.

Comment: @RoadRunner I never liked that syntax much, although is it faster than the generator?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon It seems to be slightly faster on my machine. But really its just a matter of preference I guess. I like the conciseness of `map()` in this case. I up voted regardless :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to convert string to integer and then add it. This is a handy one liner.

```
sum_ = sum(map(int, input().split('+')))
```